# NestJS use the content of a API call on another API call and return the content of the last API call

Tags: typescript, axios, rxjs, nestjs

I'm trying to use the content from the first API request on another API request but didn't had any success. I need to do the second request only after the first is done.

Right now this is what I got so far:

```
@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
  getWeather(city: GetWeatherDto): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
    return this.httpService.post(`http://localhost:3000/cities`, city).pipe(
      map((response) => response.data),
      tap((data) =>
        this.httpService
          .get(
            `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${data.city_id}&appid=APIKEY&lang=pt_br`,
          )
          .pipe(map((response) => response.data)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the switchMap operator to achieve the expected result. You might make some small changes to make it fit your needs.

```
@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
  getWeather(city: GetWeatherDto): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
    return this.httpService.post(`http://localhost:3000/cities`, city).pipe(
      switchMap((response) =>
      this.getCityWheaterById(response.data.city_id)),
      
    );
  }

 private getCityWheatherById(id: string) {
   this.httpService
          .get(
            `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?
             id=${id}&appid=APIKEY&lang=pt_br`,
          ).pipe(map((response) => response.data)),
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the status code to determine if the request was successful or not even determine if it has data if needed.

```
tap((response) =>
 if (response.status == 200){
   if (response.data){
     this.httpService.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${data.city_id}&appid=APIKEY&lang=pt_br`,).pipe(map((response) => response.data)),),
    }
 }
),
```